# Set shape of buttons in JavaFX

Tags: svg, javafx-2

I would like to ask what the easiest way is to set the shape of a button in JavaFX.

I know this can be done via CSS but I couldn't figure out how to do it. I know SVG images can be used however, I failed to get them to load. My idea is to have a red button (similar to a red STOP button) that glows when you mouse over it.  I managed the glow part for a normal button but I couldn't figure out setting the **shape**.

Comment: Actually m getting your question in the right way but i tried n i have posted one answer i hope it will help you. if you have further queries let me know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use -fx-background-radius property of CSS for setting shape of button.
shape will depend on what the parameter you provide to this property.

`-fx-background-radius: 10, 10, 10, 10;`

[image]

[image]